# why does markdown need an escape for \. to show a slash dot

Tags: markdown

why does markdown need an escape \ before the `\.path` to render this `name\of\.path` correctly. Without the escape it renders name\of.path

i.e. it must be coded as `name\of\\.path` to get name\of\.path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Markdown uses backslash as an escape character](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash):

> Markdown allows you to use backslash escapes to generate literal characters which would otherwise have special meaning in Markdown’s formatting syntax. For example, if you wanted to surround a word with literal asterisks (instead of an HTML `<em>` tag), you can use backslashes before the asterisks, like this:
>
> ```
> \*literal asterisks\*
> ```
>
> Markdown provides backslash escapes for the following characters:
>
> ```
> \   backslash
> `   backtick
> *  asterisk
> _   underscore
> {}  curly braces
> []  square brackets
> ()  parentheses
> #   hash mark
> +   plus sign
> -   minus sign (hyphen)
> .   dot
> !   exclamation mark
> ```

Note that the period ("dot") is included in this list. Therefore, a single backslash preceding a period simply escapes the period. To escape the backslash itself (and therefore display it literally) it must be escaped with a second backslash.

Comment: does anyone know what the dot does in markdown that it needs an escape for?

Comment: @claya, they are used in [ordered lists](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list). Feel free to review the Markdown syntax page I linked in my answer, which says in part "it’s possible to trigger an ordered list by accident… To avoid this, you can backslash-escape the period".